# Remote Access Setup: The subject name of the network location server certificate does not resolve correctly

Tags: remote-access, windows-server-2019

Doing a quick setup of DirectAccess on Server2k19.
One nic card, NAT'd behind a firewall. 
Server is PDC and will act as all parts of DirectAccess (RAS, NLS, and Application Server).

In the Remote Access Setup, everything is configured but when trying to Finish and apply, its giving me "The subject name of the network location server certificate does not resolve correctly. Ensure that the name resolves to the IP address of the internal network adapter of the server".

Domain Forest is acme.local and the Network location server is set to use a self-signed certificate, which defaults to: 
S=Texas, C=USA, O=Dell Inc., L=Round Rock, CN=SERVER.acme.local

The DNS Forward Lookup zone has a record for SERVER as SERVER.acme.local. and points to the internal local IP of the server 192.168.0.8 
Ive also added the same A records in DNS for : directaccess-webprobehost  and directaccess-corpconnectivityhost -- both pointing to the same 192.168.0.8 IP

What am I doing wrong?  I'll answer any questions promptly if there's more to drill down to. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to update the group policy by the following command and then try it's working.

gpupdate /force